# If a file is being tracked and you modify it, can you commit without adding?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-bash, git-add

Assuming that `<filename>` is being tracked by git, is 
`git commit -m "message" <filename>` 
possible without doing a 
`git add <filename>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you issue:

```
git commit -m "message" /file/to/save.c
```

`save.c` will be added and committed alone, provided that it is already tracked by Git.

You can find it mentioned [in the Git commit manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) (point 3 of the first list).

Comment: Actually, I had to elaborate on the answer, because answering _"Yes."_ would have been a little embarassing :)

Comment: The first point says even changed files must be "added". Could you please explain?

Comment: If you want to commit files, either tracked or untracked by Git, then you have to `git add` them before `git commit -m "message"`. Writing `git commit -m "message" file1 file2` is a **shortcut** for `git add file1; git add file2; git commit -m "message"` _provided that Git is already tracking `file1` and `file2`_ (so no file will be added by mistake). That is to say, you are "implicitly" adding them.

Comment: Thanks Stefano! Finally understood it! :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to explicitly `add` each file you modify, you could use `git commit -a -m "message"`: it will automatically add each tracked file and commit.